# How do I display a standard windows error icon for a custom exception handler?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, c++-cli, standard-icons

As the title suggests, I just want to display a standard windows error icon for a custom exception handler. What the easiest way to achieve this using WPF?

For example, the red cross in this dialog:

[alt text http://blogs.sun.com/coreqa/resource/other/report-exception.jpg](http://blogs.sun.com/coreqa/resource/other/report-exception.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look in [System.Drawing.SystemIcons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemicons.aspx). All the standard dialog icons are there for your use.

Comment: Is there a standard control I could use to display it?

Comment: Got it. A `PictureBox` control and then call `m_errorPicture->Image = System::Drawing::SystemIcons::Error->ToBitmap()`.